# Как автоматически отвечать в скрипте с командой ожидющей ответа?

Tags: bash, скрипт, sh

Хочу написать скрипт для автоснятия наград на ноде.

Команда:

```
bitsongcli tx distribution withdraw-all-rewards --from Treasure --gas auto --gas-adjustment 1.5 --gas-prices 0.025ubtsg
```

После нужно ответить: y (подтверждение выполнения).

А после нужно ввести пароль: newpassword (после чего команда выполняется)

Как это сделать в скрипте?

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Сняли награду" 
bitsongcli tx distribution withdraw-all-rewards --from Treasure  --gas auto --gas-adjustment 1.5 --gas-prices 0.025ubtsg
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так будет выглядеть конструкция для автоматического ввода данных, комментарии внутри команды нужно будет удалить, подставив необходимое.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Сняли награду" 
expect -c 'bitsongcli tx distribution withdraw-all-rewards --from Treasure  --gas auto --gas-adjustment 1.5 --gas-prices 0.025ubtsg;
#>>после нужно ответить: y (подтверждение выполнения)
#<<Ввести в кавычках текст приветствия 
    expect "text" {send -- "y\r\"};
#>>после нужно ввести пароль: newpassword (после чего команда выполняется)
#<<Приглашение ввода пароля указать вместо password:
    expect "password:" {send -- "newpassword\r"};
    interact'
```

В случае если команда expect не зарегистрирована в системе, нужно будет установить пакет

Ubuntu:`apt-get install expect`
CentOS:`yum install expect`

Comment: Калсс, щас попробую мне кажется это должно сработать)

Comment: По всей видимости не тестирование не успешно?

Comment: Тестрирование реально прошло без успешно, но Я понял логику как написать что мне нужно, команда expect слушает ответы и в случае если прописать праильный ответ нужно использовать команду сенд с необходимым ответом

Comment: Все верно, об этом я писал в комментариях к строкам.

Answer (score 0):

`bitsongcli tx distribution withdraw-all-rewards --from Treasure  --gas auto --gas-adjustment 1.5 --gas-prices 0.025ubtsg < input.txt`

input.txt:

`y
password`

Может поможет?

Comment: если создать файл input.txt выдает ошибку ERROR: Error reading passphrase: EOF

Comment: если прямо в скрипте написать то тоже ошибка: ./reward.sh: line 4: input.txt: No such file or directory
./reward.sh: line 6: input.txt:: command not found
./reward.sh: line 8: y: command not found
./reward.sh: line 9: newpassword: command not found

Comment: @user370747 После строки с паролем, в файле попробуйте нажать Enter и сохранитесь. То-есть после строки с паролем должна быть пустая строка.

Comment: ошибка:ERROR: Error reading passphrase: EOF

Comment: @user370747 Ну значит ква, не судьба, надо думать дальше.